# Get actual cell value of excel cell with POI without defining a datatype

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi

I catch my cells from an .xls file like this:

```
cell.getStringCellValue();
```

But since some of the cells are numeric, I have to do this instead:

```
                try
                {
                    cells[colIx] = cell.getStringCellValue();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e)
                {
                    cells[colIx] = String.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                }
```

since it's getting a double and then converts it to a string this results in some unwanted operations like:

- 1 converts into 1.0 (not that kind of a big problem)
- 16711680 converts to 1.671168E7

How do I solve this and get the actual cell value instead of some converted numbers? Also, all of the cells are defined as default in excel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Apache POI `DataFormatter`'s `formatCellValue(Cell cell)` method as it returns the formatted value of a cell as a String regardless of the cell type.

According to [DataFormatter](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html) doc -

> DataFormatter contains methods for formatting the value stored in an
>   Cell. This can be useful for reports and GUI presentations when you
>   need to display data exactly as it appears in Excel. Supported formats
>   include currency, SSN, percentages, decimals, dates, phone numbers,
>   zip codes, etc.

Sample code

```
DataFormatter dataFormatter= new DataFormatter();

// Inside loop
String cellValueStr = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell);
```

Answer (score 0):

try using cell.getCellType() as you have

1. numeric
2. date
3. numeric in scientific notation